# Writing based on the context or theme

Tags: creative-writing, word-choice

I'm totally new to this field as well as this site and going to learn on my own and need a direction for this specific area I want to learn.

I want to understand what I need to learn and which direction I need to go to acquire these specific skills and I can use an example of script (background voice) of this show called Dragon's Den.

What fascinated me is the creative use of words related to the idea/industry/field of the idea pitch presented, recycling it's meaning with a twist.

For example, in this [show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyCqSD4Bl2Q) (15m), the pitch was for switching plans for energy companies. The creative words used within the context.

> new laws protecting personal data could **short-circuit** their chances (3:11)
>
> not joining their **utility** revolution (4:32), *double meaning utility as to energy company as well as the idea website as a utility.*
>
> ready to **supply** his verdict on the proposition (5:35)
>
> **electrifies** the den using his track record (7:10)
>
> encouraging the entrepreneurs to **switch** to her deal (8:42)
>
> is she about to **turn up the heat** in the dead (8:50)
>
> two **switched-on** dragons (14:44)

The question is around how can I acquired the skills to recycle the use of words creatively, any books or trainings appreciated.

P.S. Is there a some specific terminology for such creative use of words in the creative writing industry?

Comment: I think you just have to write descriptively. Practice writing descriptions. There are lots of ways to describe stuff. You can describe an object with units of measurement. You can describe an object with words of emotion. I don't think that there is a real term for this.

Comment: @DoubleU thanks for articulating it for me, your comment gave ma a perspective on how to approach this way of writing. Any books can you recommend around the same area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wordplay.

> Word play or wordplay[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_play) (also: play-on-words) is a literary technique
>   and a form of wit in which words used become the main subject of the
>   work, primarily for the purpose of intended effect or amusement.

The [Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_play) this is lifted from gives some examples of plays and books you could read to help you in your quest.

There are also dozens of books on the subject, like Wisdom & Wordplay by Robert Eddison. But if you search on Amazon, you'll find a lot more.

Good luck!